# AngularJS not showing $scope

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I know this question has been answered but given solutions didn't work for me. Everything looks okey, but the contento between curly brackets it's not showing on screen.

```
    <div ng-controller="Hello">
        <p>The ID is {{greeting.ip}}</p>
        <p>The content is {{greeting.ip}}</p>
    </div>
```

The controller is the folling:

```
 'use strict';
angular.module('sbAdminApp')
    .controller('Hello',['$scope','$http', function ($scope, $http) {

$http.get('http://ip.jsontest.com/')
    .then(function (data) {
            $scope.greeting = data;
    console.log($scope.greeting);
        });
    }]);
```

And in my app.js, im declaring this:

```
       .state('dashboard.test', {
            templateUrl: 'views/test.html',
            url: '/test',
            controller: 'Hello',
            resolve: {
                loadMyFiles: function ($ocLazyLoad) {
                    return $ocLazyLoad.load({
                        name: 'sbAdminApp',
                        files: ['scripts/controllers/helloWorld.js']
                    })
                }
            }
        })
```

The JSON URL from where I'm getting the data is [this.](http://ip.jsontest.com/)

And here are the pics with the output from the console:

[image: It looks ok!]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$scope.greeting = data;` This line is wrong.

It should be `$scope.greeting = data.data;`

**EDIT:**

Because you are assigning your response from the server to that variable and you need only the data returned from the API call. You response object contains stuff like headers and status code and the `data` property which actually contains your the data you need like `id` and stuff. If you want to get the `id` from your response object you can do it like this: `greeting.data.id`.

I always name my `response` variable `res` or `response` so not to mess it up. Like this:

```
$http.get('http://ip.jsontest.com/')
    .then(function (res) {
            $scope.greeting = res.data;
            console.log($scope.greeting);
        });
    }]);
```

Comment: totally worked. I feel a bit stupid now. Could you explain me why? Thanks!

Comment: Edit has been provided. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you're doing the following:

```
$scope.greeting = data;
```

But according to your `JSON` it should be:

```
$scope.greeting = data.data;
```

The `data` variable holds the whole `JSON` object, and you want the data key from it.